# Remove dynamically created elements by class name Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, in plain terms I am creating a Chrome Extension that so far can only save links from the internet but not delete them. What I want to add is a "remove" button for deleting unwanted links. So far I haven't got that to work.

The buttons I want to remove are added using JavaScript. Each new block of HTML features a "remove" button but clicking that button does nothing. I have tried binding listeners to each element using a for loop but that doesn't seem to work.

The code runs without errors and I'm certain that the issue is a slight oversight but I have only just started using JavaScript so I'm lost for solutions at the moment.

I have included all the code because I don't want to leave out anything that might be imperative to finding a solution.

It starts with the code for adding a link, followed by removing a single link and then removing all links at once. Thank you all for any help, really want to get this working.

**https://github.com/mmmamer/Drop** Repository for the rest of the code. Mainly popup.html and popup.css.

```
var urlList = [];
var i = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  getUrlListAndRestoreInDom();
  // event listener for the button inside popup window
  document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', addLink);
});

function addLink() {
  var url = document.getElementById("saveLink").value;
  addUrlToListAndSave(url);
  addUrlToDom(url);
}

function getUrlListAndRestoreInDom() {
  chrome.storage.local.get({
    urlList: []
  }, function(data) {
    urlList = data.urlList;
    urlList.forEach(function(url) {
      addUrlToDom(url);
    });
  });
}

function addUrlToDom(url) {
  // change the text message
  document.getElementById("saved-pages").innerHTML = "<h2>Saved pages</h2>";
  var newEntry = document.createElement('li');
  var newLink = document.createElement('a');
  var removeButton = document.createElement('button');

  removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
  //removeButton.createElement('button');
  removeButton.type = "button";
  removeButton.className = "remove";


  newLink.textContent = url;
  newLink.setAttribute('href', url);
  newLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  newEntry.appendChild(newLink)
  newEntry.appendChild(removeButton);

  newEntry.className = "listItem";

  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newEntry);

}

function addUrlToListAndSave(url) {
  urlList.push(url);
  saveUrlList();
  //}
}

function saveUrlList(callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({
    urlList
  }, function() {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      //If there was no callback provided, don't try to call it.
      callback();
    }
  });
}

// remove a single bookmark item
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  getUrlListAndRestoreInDom();
  var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

  function listenI(i) {
    allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => removeMe(i));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    listenI(i);
  }
});

function removeMe(i) {
  var fullList = documents.getElementsByClassName('listItem');
  listItem[i].parentNode.removeChild(listItem[i]);
}

//remove all button
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    document.getElementById("remove-all").addEventListener('click', function() {
        var removeList = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");
        while(removeList[0]) {
            removeList[0].parentNode.removeChild(removeList[0]);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between `restore()` and `getUrlListAndRestoreInDom()`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to add that a lot of the code is pinched from different sources on the internet. But now that you point it out I think they perform the same function. I'll revise my question and code and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.storage.local.get()` is asynchronous. So when you try to add the event listeners to the Remove buttons, they're not in the DOM yet.

You can add the listener in the `addUrlToDom()` function instead. That way you'll also add the event listener when you create new buttons.

```
function addUrlToDom(url) {
  // change the text message
  document.getElementById("saved-pages").innerHTML = "<h2>Saved pages</h2>";
  var newEntry = document.createElement('li');
  var newLink = document.createElement('a');
  var removeButton = document.createElement('button');

  removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
  //removeButton.createElement('button');
  removeButton.type = "button";
  removeButton.className = "remove";


  newLink.textContent = url;
  newLink.setAttribute('href', url);
  newLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  newEntry.appendChild(newLink)
  newEntry.appendChild(removeButton);
  removeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var anchor = this.previousElementSibling;
    var url = anchor.getAttribute("href");
    removeUrlAndSave(url);
    this.parentNode.remove();
  });

  newEntry.className = "listItem";

  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newEntry);

}

function removeUrlAndSave(url) {
  var index = urlList.indexOf(url);
  if (index != -1) {
    urlList.splice(index, 1);
    saveUrlList();
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked! but you already knew that. Thank you very much for the contribution. I can't help but feel at a loss because I'm not sure _how_ it worked exactly. But binding the listeners at the moment of creation is perfect.